# Why this package cannot be dropped?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-deadlocks

I cannot drop a package in oracle 11g. After 'drop package' session stops responding and it looks like deadlock. But there are no locked objects returned from query:

```
select *
 from v$locked_object lo
 join dba_objects o on lo.object_id = o.object_id
where o.object_type = 'PACKAGE';
```

How to find out what is wrong with the package? And how finally to release all locks and drop it?

Comment: Do you have an open session that's in the middle of a long-running call to a procedure in the package?

Comment: @Alex, the situation is reproducing in the only session, and I almost sure (99%) that no one else was using the package then. Anyhow, a session holding a lock for an object should appear in `select * from v$locked_object`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The big hammer approach is to restart or bounce the database.  That will terminate all sessions and allow you to drop the package.

As Alex Poole suggests you may have another session accessing the package and locking it.  I sure hope this is a development box. If it is look at v$session and kill any sessions that you used to access the package.

Comment: Killing sessions is helpful, but I am trying to find a way to gather all available information about package state in the moment of deadlock (if there is one). In all, I need to find which object initiated lock on the package - so the question is why (`select * from v$locked_object ...`) does not show anything about a lock, but the package _seems to be locked_.